# How to do html redirect in JSP?

Tags: html, jsp, variables, redirect

I have the following JSP :

```
<%
  String Target_Url=request.getSession().getAttribute("Target_Url").toString();
  Target_Url="http://www.yahoo.com";
%>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">   
    <head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        if (window.top.location != window.location) 
        {
          window.top.location.href=window.location.href; 
        }
      </script>
      <META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=${Target_Url}">

    </head>
  ...
</html>
```

It's inside a frame, and should redirect to the top level location, but it's not doing that, it keeps redirect to it self, but if I hard code it like the following, it works :

```
<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://www.yahoo.com">
```

I guess : `content="0;URL=${Target_Url}"` is incorrect, what's the correct format ?

Comment: Never do HTML redirects. If you want to do a redirect, do it in HTTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct format:

```
<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=<%=Target_Url%>">
```